# Aliasing function in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell

The following code doesn't compile:

```
import Data.Bits
xor2 = xor
```

However, once I added the type info, it compiles:

```
import Data.Bits
xor2 :: Bits a => a->a->a
xor2 = xor
```

I can't explain this. Any explanations?

Comment: What error do you see?  I'm going to guess that this problem originates from the dreaded monomorphism restriction.  Add `{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}` at the top of your file, or `:set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction` in GHCi.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a problem with the [dreaded monomorphism restriction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction) (MMR), which is enabled by default. The MMR is a rule that forces top-level bindings that do not look like functions (ie `x = ...` vs `x a = ...`) to have monomorphic bindings unless they have an explicit polymorphic type signature.

The problem is that `Bits a => a  -> a -> a` is polymorphic (note the type variable `a`), and Haskell does not know how to choose a default type for `a` that satisfies the `Bits` constraint.

Once you add a type signature, the MMR is appeased and you can have a top-level binding that's polymorphic. Another option is to "eta-expand" the definition by adding a named argument; since `xor2` now syntactically looks like a function, the MMR does not apply:

```
xor2 x = xor x
```

You can also turn the MMR off with a language extension. You can put this at the top of your module:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
```